# Jumping to one character past the search

Tags: search, normal-mode

I understand that `f` jumps to the first matching character, and `t` jumps to one character just before the first matching character

For example, given the string `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL`, I would like to change it to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL`. with the caret on `V` I should press `4f_lct_SRC` to achieve that

But I'm wondering if there is a key that allows me to jump to one character just *after* the first matching character, so I can omit the `l` offset, (which frankly trips me up sometimes) and turn the sequence into `4  %SOMETHING%  _ct_SRC`

I understand that this can be accomplished by macros (or in this specific example circumvented by a substitution), but I'm wondering if this functionality exists out of the box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use search, e.g. `/_DST/s+` to move the cursor to the `D` of the DST part. The part after the search pattern is the offset, so `s+` moves the cursor 1 character to the right of the **s**tart of the pattern, while, e.g. `e-2` would move the cursor 2 character to the left of the **e**nd of the pattern.

See the help at `:h search-offset`

Comment: I actually didn't know about search offsets. That would help a lot, neat.

However in the general case I would need to look for something after a `_`, and cannot rely on a string like `DST` existing all the time. A solution would ideally require only knowledge of `_`.

But still, search offsets, looks useful.

Comment: You can also combine this with a count, e.g. `4/_/s+`

Comment: Is there a default keybind that does this for me though? I'd prefer to not have to append a `/s+` or map a binding.

Comment: you would have to map this to a new key combination.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but why are you not using `fD`? That puts you right on the D.

Furthermore, you can define underline as a keyword via `set iskeyword-=_`. In your situation, this allows the change via `cw`. That is quite handy.

So in total just `fDcwSCR`.

Last but not least you can roll out the big guns and employ plugins like [CamelCaseMotion](https://github.com/bkad/CamelCaseMotion) or [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak).

Comment: I can't assume that what comes after `_` will always be a `D`. I can only assume that there is some text after a `_` that I want to edit

Comment: No, of course not. That is just meant as a specific answer to your specific example. And, if this is something you need a lot, you should have a look at  those movement plugins; they may well suite your needs.

Comment: @Wagk, with vim-sneak, you can do `fDSct_SRC`, which is one character less than your original solution.